# Issue with sending image from user to the bot

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying with a sample code to send an image from the user side to the backend bot server.

I am using the following sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-ReceiveAttachment/app.js

but when I am importing this package

```
var request = require('request-promise');
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/cts461006/jitu/OldBotCode/TestingAsosBotOnOldBot/node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:34:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cts461006/jitu/OldBotCode/TestingAsosBotOnOldBot/node_modules/request-promise/lib/rp.js:28:1)
```

Please guide us?

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running? I installed modules and ran the `core-ReceiveAttachement` sample without any errors using `Node@6.10.2` & `npm@3.10.10`

Answer (score 0):

try installing the latest version of request-promise by running the command:

```
npm install request-promise --save
```

if that does not work you could try deleting your node_modules directory and then running "npm install" in your terminal.